# Failed to extract value from json output

Tags: json, ansible, jinja2

I am trying to extract the value of `snapshot_policy_schedules.snapshot_schedule_info` from the below list:

```json
[
        {
        'enabled': 'true', 
        'policy': 'default-DR', 
        'policy_owner': 'vserver-admin', 
        'snapshot_policy_schedules': {
                'snapshot_schedule_info': [
                        {
                                'count': '6', 
                                'prefix': 'hourly', 
                                'schedule': 'hourly', 
                                'snapmirror_label': '-'
                        }, 
                        {
                                'count': '2', 
                                'prefix': 'daily', 
                                'schedule': 'daily', 
                                'snapmirror_label': 'daily'
                        }, 
                        {
                                'count': '2', 
                                'prefix': 'weekly', 
                                'schedule': 'weekly', 
                                'snapmirror_label': 'weekly'
                        }
                ]
        },
        'total_schedules': '3', 
        'vserver_name': 'net'
        }
]
```

However I am getting the error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'list object' has no attribute 'snapshot_policy_schedules'"}
```

This is my code:

```
 {% for schedule in policy.snapshot_policy_schedules.snapshot_schedule_info %}
            {% if schedule.schedule == 'weekly' %}
                {% set policy_weekly = schedule.count %}
            {% endif %}

            {% if schedule.schedule == 'daily' %}
                {% set policy_daily = schedule.count %}
            {% endif %}

            {% if schedule.schedule == 'hourly' %}
                {% set policy_hourly = schedule.count %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: What is `policy`? Is it the full list? Could you explain what debug you made to get your list? So we can have a grasp at what your entire data structure is.

Comment: What I suspect with the information currently present: you need to do `policy.0.snapshot_policy_schedules.snapshot_schedule_info`, but won't you have other elements in that top list that you still want to loop on?

Comment: `policy` is basically the json return mentioned in the question. It contains only one item (exactly like the question). However, when I do `policy.0.snapshot_policy_schedules.snapshot_schedule_info`, the following error is shown: `fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: list object has no element 0"}`

Comment: Validate [JSON](https://jsonlint.com/) before reporting errors.

Comment: @VladimirBotka this is the json as printed by ansible.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a list of list? You should rally show us your `debug` step as well as the full task output.

Comment: It's not [valid JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp). It's [YAML](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-the-difference-between-yaml-and-json/). `"YAML is a superset of JSON, it can parse JSON with a YAML parser"`.

Comment: It is indeed odd that a `debug` would output you invalid JSON (using quotes instead of double quotes)

Comment: Who writes YAML using the JSON format?

Comment: @axiac Ansible playbook are YAML, but the underlaying data provided by the tasks are in JSON format. So most probably, the OP have an output from another task and then parses it.

Comment: @axiac, `YAML is a superset of JSON`. To answer your question `Who writes YAML using the JSON format?` the answer is: I do (and you can find other examples as well). Very often [JSON is used in YAML](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-linux-postinstall/blob/master/vars/main.yml.sample)  to improve readability. If you want Ansible to produce valid JSON use filter `to_json` or `to_nice_json`.

Comment: @axiac, to be fair, the data in your example is [valid YAML](http://www.yamllint.com/). Still, you might want to simplify it first to find out what is causing the error.

Comment: @vladimirBotka Maybe the data in the question is valid YAML but it is not valid JSON. The same for the data in the page you linked in your previous comment. But I learned a new thing today, thank you. I hope I can use this information in our tools.

Answer (score 1):

Q: **"*'list object' has no attribute 'snapshot_policy_schedules'*"**

A: The *'list object'* i.e. the variable *policy* is a list. You probably want to address the first element

```yaml
{% for schedule in policy.0.snapshot_policy_schedules.snapshot_schedule_info %}
```

---

For example, simplified JSON

```yaml
{
    "policy": [{
    "schedules": {
        "info": [
        {"count": "6","prefix": "hourly"},
        {"count": "2","prefix": "daily"},
        {"count": "2","prefix": "weekly"}]
        }
    }]
}
```

and simplified Jinja

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |-
          {% for item in policy.0.schedules.info %}
          {{ item.count }} {{ item.prefix }}
          {% endfor %}
```

give

```yaml
  msg: |-
    6 hourly
    2 daily
    2 weekly
```

Comment: when I add `.0` I get the following error: `fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: list object has no element 0"}`

Comment: still the same error. It's what I tried earlier anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to get the first element of a sequence is to use the [`first`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#first) filter of Jinja:

```
{% for schedule in (policy | first).snapshot_policy_schedules.snapshot_schedule_info %}
```

Comment: It also doesnt work. `fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: No first item, sequence was empty."}`